# SKlearn MLP Regressor - predicted values stuck at zero

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, time-series, regression

The problem is just as the title says. Tried inverse_transforming the predictions, but it doesn't help.
Here is the code:

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from datetime import datetime

with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Create a DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert "periodFrom" timestamps to numerical features (time elapsed since the minimum timestamp)
df['periodFrom'] = pd.to_datetime(df['periodFrom'])
# df['periodFrom_numeric'] = (df['periodFrom'] - df['periodFrom'].min()).dt.total_seconds()
df['periodFrom_numeric'] = df['periodFrom'].values.reshape(-1, 1)


# Handle missing values
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
df['value'] = imputer.fit_transform(df[['value']])

# Extract features and target values from training data
X_train = df['periodFrom_numeric'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = df['value'].values

# Load new data points from new_data_json.json
with open('new_data_json.json', 'r') as file:
    new_data = json.load(file)

# Create a DataFrame from the new data
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

# Convert "periodFrom" timestamps in new data to numerical features
new_df['periodFrom'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['periodFrom'])
new_df['periodFrom_numeric'] = new_df['periodFrom'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Handle missing values in the new data (impute with mean from training data)
new_df['value'] = imputer.transform(new_df[['value']])

# Extract features from new data points
X_new = new_df['periodFrom_numeric'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Standardize the data
scaler = RobustScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_new = scaler.transform(X_new)

# Create and train the neural network
model = MLPRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Use the trained model to make predictions on the new data points
predictions = model.predict(X_new).reshape(-1, 1)

# Plot the actual values and the predicted values throughout the time period
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot actual values from training data
plt.scatter(df['periodFrom'], df['value'], label='Actual Values', marker='o')

# Plot predicted values for new time periods
plt.scatter(new_df['periodFrom'], predictions, label='Predicted Values', marker='o', color="green")

plt.scatter(new_df['periodFrom'], new_df['value'], label='Actual values the model had to predict', marker="o", color="red")

plt.xlabel('Time Period (periodFrom)')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Actual and Predicted Values throughout the Time Period')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Tried inverse transforming the predictions, but it jambles up the plot. Here is an example of the data:

```
    {
        "id": "1Physical Flowhour2023-07-20 06:00:00 +00:002023-07-20 07:00:00 +00:00BG-TSO-0001ITP-00128exitkWh/h_PD266",
        "dataSet": 1,
        "indicator": "Physical Flow",
        "periodType": "hour",
        "periodFrom": "2023-07-20T08:00:00+02:00",
        "periodTo": "2023-07-20T09:00:00+02:00",
        "operatorKey": "BG-TSO-0001",
        "tsoEicCode": "21X-BG-A-A0A0A-C",
        "operatorLabel": "Bulgartransgaz",
        "pointKey": "ITP-00128",
        "pointLabel": "Kulata (BG) / Sidirokastron (GR)",
        "tsoItemIdentifier": "21Z000000000020C",
        "directionKey": "exit",
        "unit": "kWh/h",
        "itemRemarks": null,
        "generalRemarks": null,
        "value": 3742835,
        "lastUpdateDateTime": "2023-07-21T10:53:48+02:00",
        "isUnlimited": null,
        "flowStatus": "Confirmed",
        "interruptionType": null,
        "restorationInformation": null,
        "capacityType": null,
        "capacityBookingStatus": null,
        "isCamRelevant": true,
        "isNA": null,
        "originalPeriodFrom": "",
        "isCmpRelevant": "",
        "bookingPlatformKey": "",
        "bookingPlatformLabel": "",
        "bookingPlatformURL": "",
        "interruptionCalculationRemark": null
    }
```

Also if you think there might be another, more suitable model, I'd be glad to hear. ARIMA doesn't work - too big residuals.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing your training dataset down to just a few samples and make the `MLPRegressor` model bigger (using `hidden_layers=`). Fit the MLP on that smaller training set, and see what it scores on that train set (look at the *train* score - ignore the test score on `X_new` for now). The model should overfit quite easily on the small train set and yield a more reasonable train score. If not, something might be wrong with the data being fed in. You can work back from there to see where things fail. It may help if you share some training data.

In terms of other models to try, consider `sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor`. That will likely fit more quickly and require less tuning to get started. Does it perform any better?